# Add "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" when writing a comment

Tags: feature-request

When I'm writing a comment on **skeptics.se**, it takes a lot of time to create it and fix it and I use all the characters allowed that it looks like a small paragraph.

Many times, my browser went back automatically when pressing backspace (to delete something), and (on my macbook if you slide two fingers on the left of the pad, it will go back), it is really annoying and it happened with me many times.

Please add:

> You haven't posted your comment yet, are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?